# std::string, difference between string val and string val = ""

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I am trying to pass an std::string as a default argument to a function.

I'm trying like follows

```
void string_fun(int i, string val = "", int j = 10)
// void string_fun(int i, string val, int j = 10) // <-- error since no default value
{
    cout << "values " << endl;
    cout << "i: " << i << endl;
    cout << "val: " << val << endl;
    cout << "j: " << j << endl;
}

void ret_fun()
{
    string fun;
    cout << "values " << endl;
    cout << "fun: " << fun << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string_fun(3);
    ret_fun();
    return 0;
}
```

I heard that the default constructor of a string will initialize the string, if that is correct what will be the value of that? See here if I'm using only `string val` as the argument to the function, I'll  get compilation error. But when I print the string both `val` and `fun` I'm getting the same output. My question is what make the two string different in case of their values, since `string val = ""` also creates a blank string.

Comment: Consider using `string val = {}` instead of `string val = ""`. The former uses the default constructor, whereas the latter uses an implicit constructor to create a string from a `const char*`. The former might be more efficient. In particular, it is declared with _noexcept_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at an **argument list for a function**, the rules are therefore different. It doesn't matter that `std::string` has a default constructor.

The point is that the language's rules for argument lists make sure that you allow or disallow a caller to omit parameters from the call. When a default value is given, the caller may omit the parameter and the default values is used instead. Without a default value, the caller *must* supply an appropriate parameter.

If you leave out the default value of the second parameter, your call

```
string_fun(3);
```

does not compile as it requires at least two parameters. You could even use the default constructor in the call:

```
string_fun(3, string());
```